# Export NumPy array as NetCDF4 file

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm trying to export a simple 2D NumPy array as a `.nc` (NetCDF) file. I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956270/convert-a-numpy-dataset-to-netcdf) example without exit.

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc

# Array example
x = np.random.random((16,16))

# Create NetCDF4 dataset
with nc.Dataset('data/2d_array.nc', 'w', 'NETCDF4') as ncfile:
    ncfile.createDimension('rows', x.shape[0])
    ncfile.createDimension('cols', x.shape[1])
    data_var = ncfile.createVariable('data', 'int32', ('rows', 'cols'))
    data_var = x
```

However, where I import the array again is all zero:

```
# Read file
with nc.Dataset('data/2d_array.nc', 'r') as ncfile:
    array = ncfile.variables['data'][:]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're rebinding the `data_var` to refer to the numpy array rather than setting the data of the variable you created.  Try:

```
data_var[:] = x
```

instead.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting your head around the difference, check out https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns or https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for text version